# Javasqript + Servlet

Tags: javascript, servlet

А у меня ни дня без вопроса. Мне нужно передать переменную из javasqript в servlet. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно сделать это, все что нагуглила написано на английском языке, что тяжело для понимания. Может быть есть примеры на русском (объяснения) или кто-то может сам объяснить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправить:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("get", "http://path.to.server/servletName?parameter=value", true);
req.send();
```

Принять(java HttpServlet):

```
Object value = req.getParameter("paramater");
```

Comment: Исходя из вашего кода, вы значение берете у параметра в сслыке, мне же нужно отправить переменную. 
 function handleRightClick1() {
        var x = document.getElementById("abc1").getAttribute("value");
        word = word + x;
Мне нужно отправить word.

Comment: req.open("get", "http://path.to.server/servletName?word=" + word, true);